# SNR of original signal and quantized signal - MATLAB

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

If I wanted to get the SNR of a quantized audio signal, would I subtract the quantized signal from the original (which would give me the noise?) and then calculate the power of this noise and compare it to the power of the original signal?

Such as, SNR(dB)=10*log(original power/noise power)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is the **quantization noise**. It is not just “noise” because the input has noise as well, and you don’t include that noise in your result.

Comment: How would I scale(?) the two signals, the signal before been quantized and the signal after, so I can correctly measure the SNR?